# send the unix output to a csv file

Tags: bash, unix

I want to put the output data from unix command to a csv file.
Suppose the output which I am getting is :

```
A
B
C
```

I want to put this data in .csv file as

```
A B C
```

in three different columns but same row.

Comment: Okay, great. You've described the problem you're trying to solve. Now, tell us what steps you've taken in your attempts to solve it.

Comment: I tried using operator  >> to csv file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
printf '%s\n' A B C | paste -sd ' ' >> file.csv
```

or more classical for a CSV (delimiter with a `,` :

```
printf '%s\n' A B C | paste -sd ',' >> file.csv
```

`printf '%s\n' A B C` is just an example to have the same sample input as you. My solution works with spaces in a same line too.

**EDIT**  from your comments, you seems to need to treat with a `for` loop, so :

```
for i in {0..5}; do printf '%s\n' {A..C} | paste -sd " " >> file.csv; done
```

or in pseudo code :

```
for ...:
    unix_command | paste -sd " " >> file.csv
endfor
```

Comment: Actually these outputs SAY A B C will be the words and will be stored in a text file

Comment: Isn't what you expected ? If not, be more concise please.

Comment: Sorry,Trying to be more concise.See I will run a for loop and from each loop i will get 3 results,I am trying to put this 3 results in csv file

Comment: Hummmm, this is **exactly** the purpose of my snippet above Django.

Comment: for every output the data need to be in column and for every for loop the result should be in next row

Comment: In your edited post you are mentioning the number of time the loop will run(In my scenario it is not fixed) and the A...C the outputs ....which I will not be known

Comment: And so ? Just try to understand my command and adapt it for your needs. The number of iterations doesn't change anything in the logic.

Comment: Anyhow,Thanks for your help,I will try using your concept.

Answer (score 6):

```
unix_command | tr "\n" " " > file.csv
```

or

```
unix_command | awk 'ORS=FS' > file.csv
```

Disadvantage in both cases: one trailing space

Answer (score 2):

For my understanding, @Django needs three line into one line.

```
paste -d ' ' - - - < infile
```

If you need output as csv format (split by `,`), you can use this

```
paste -d ',' - - - < infile
```

Here is the test result

```
$ cat infile
Manoj Mishra
Japan
Environment.
Michael Jackson
America
Environment.

$ paste -d ',' - - - < infile

Manoj Mishra,Japan,Environment.
Michael Jackson,America,Environment.
```

Comment: Sorry but your snippet is not working in my case.There are space and i am not getting what is infile here

Comment: mate, you need provide sample input first.

Comment: ok Consider the sample input which are in text file.First Line-Manoj Mishra.2nd line Japan .3rd line Environment.

Comment: there will be many lines but i want to get three lines/output one by one and have to print in csv in first 3 columns,next 3 lines/output will be in 1st 3 columns of next row of csv file

Answer (score 1):

## A more general answer

If the output of your command is multi-line and you want to put the
*quoted* output in csv format, `n` items per line, the following script
could be handy.

---

The `groupby` program reads from `stdin` and

1. quotes each input line
2. groups `n` quoted input lines in a csv record, using a comma as a separator

optionally, using the `-s` optional argument, the program discards the
last line of its output if said last line doesn't contain exactly `n`
items.

The `-h` option, as usual, echoes an usage line and exits.

Specifying another option the program prints the usage line and exits
in error.

### The code

```
% cat groupby
#!/bin/sh
usage () { echo Usage: $0 [-s] n --- -s is for \"strict\", outputs only records of n items. ; exit $1 ; }
s=0
while getopts :sh o ; do
    case "${o}" in
        s) s=1 ; shift ;;
        h) usage 0     ;;
        *) usage 1     ;;
    esac
done
awk -v n=$1 -v s=$s -v q='"' '
NR==1   {buf = q $0 q ; next}
NR%n==1 {print buf; buf = q $0 q ; next}
        {buf = buf "," q $0 q}
END     {if(!s||NR%n==0)print buf}'
%
```

### An example of usage

```
% chmod +x groupby
% echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | ./groupby 3
"1","2","3"
"4","5"
% echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6" | ./groupby 3
"1","2","3"
"4","5","6"
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7" | ./groupby 3
"1","2","3"
"4","5","6"
"7"
% echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8" | ./groupby -s 4
"1","2","3","4"
"5","6","7","8"
% echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7" | ./groupby -s 4
"1","2","3","4"
%
```

### A different angle

I changed the defaults to suit best the OP requirements, and introduced other options, see the usage string for details

```
#!/bin/sh
usage () { echo 'Usage: '$0' [-s] [-q quote_char] [-c separator_char] n
  Reads lines from stdin and prints them grouped by n and separated by spaces.
  Optional arguments:
    -s is for "strict", outputs only records of n items;
    -q quote_char, forces quoting of each input line;
    -c separator_char, changes the field separator,
       interesting alternatives are tab, comma, semicolon etc;
    -h prints this help and exits.' ; exit $1 ; }

# Default options
s=0 ; q='' ; c=' '

# Treatment of optional arguments
while getopts :shc:q: o ; do
    case "${o}" in
        s) s=1 ;         ;;
        c) c="${OPTARG}" ;;
        q) q="${OPTARG}" ;;
        h) usage 0       ;;
        *) usage 1       ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND-1))

# awk code
awk -v n=$1 -v s=$s -v q="$q"  -v c="$c" '
    NR==1   {buf = q $0 q ; next}
    NR%n==1 {print buf; buf = q $0 q ; next}
            {buf = buf c q $0 q}
    END     {if(!s||NR%n==0)print buf}'
```

Answer (score -3):

just use [***`xargs`***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs).

---

eg:

```
less filename| xargs >> filename.csv
```

Comment: `... | xargs -n3 > ...` would create rows with three elements each.