# Send output to a csv file

Tags: macos, shell, unix, command-line

I am writing a script to write an output to a csv file. I followed the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388136/send-the-unix-output-to-a-csv-file) from stack but it doesn't work on macOS. It gives the 
error:

```
usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...
```

Following is the accepted answer:

```
printf '%s\n' A B C | paste -sd ' ' >> file.csv
```

or more classical for a CSV (delimiter with a , :

```
printf '%s\n' A B C | paste -sd ',' >> file.csv
printf '%s\n' A B C
```

is just an example to have the same sample input as you. My solution works with spaces in a same line too.

EDIT from your comments, you seems to need to treat with a for loop, so :

```
for i in {0..5}; do printf '%s\n' {A..C} | paste -sd " " >> file.csv; done
```

or in pseudo code :

```
for ...:
    unix_command | paste -sd " " >> file.csv
endfor
```

Comment: Do you get anything more specific than “doesn't work?” Such as an error message?

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: Thanks. I have no macOS, and under Linux the `paste` command is acceptable in the form given. From the message it could be that your `paste` either (1) does not like the `d` and `s` options being grouped (try `-s -d ' '`), or (2) insists on having a file name specified. In the latter case you could try a minus sign and hope that it is interpreted as std-in. If you have an `xargs` command you can also try `xargs -n3` instead of the `paste`.

Comment: I can confirm that on MacOS, this works: `printf '%s\n' A B C | paste -sd ',' - >> ~/Desktop/file.csv`.  You can use a space as a delimiter too.